# jQuery popup issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, bpopup

I need a solution for this, I am using [bPopup plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bpopup)

But, I believe that it's a simple jQuery function. I need to pass single variable, say sales id when someone clicks the  tag

Following is the function code, please suggest me some way to achieve it

```
$("a.sales_info").bind("click", function(){
            $("#popup").bPopup({contentContainer:'#pContent',loadUrl:"test.html p"});
            return false
});
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to pass the variable to the page you are requesting then you can append the variable as a querystring to the URL.

Comment: there are multiple <a> tags, and I need to pass unique sales id to each <a> tag

Comment: How can I get id of the <a> tag which I just click using jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved above thing using "this" for example *this.id*

Thanks Everyone for all the help & support.

Still, suggestions/comments are welcome :)